# Major gridline at origin not showing up in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to get the major gridline at `y=0` to display. I have major gridlines turned on, I want the box/border turned off and I have tried manually setting the major gridlines but this has not allowed the `y=0` line to display.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.legend(loc='best')
#plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.2, 0.2))
plt.grid(True, 'major', 'y')
plt.box(on=None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn clipping off for the grid lines:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.get_gridlines()[0].set_clip_on(False)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks! I'd found another (not as good) way to show them too which was by setting the ylim lower bound slightly below 0 with `plt.ylim(-0.05,1)`